# How to compare the value of 2 registers/variables together in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, compare

I am trying to compare the values of 2 variables to each other in assembly. I'm moving 3 into both variables. I want to compare the variables to each other. I've tried using brackets on each register and variable when comparing and it will not compile, such as cmp [eax], [ebx] and cmp [num], [num1]. Is there a way to compare them to each other or can you only compare by using cmp [num], byte 3? Thanks for the help.

```
section .data
hello:     db 'Hello world!',10    ; 'Hello world!' plus a linefeed character
helloLen:  equ $-hello             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string

section .bss
num resb 1
num1 resb 1

section .text
global _start

_start:

mov [num], byte 3
mov [num1], byte 3

mov eax, [num]
mov ebx, [num1]

cmp eax, ebx
jne end

add [num], byte '0'
mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
mov ecx,num        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
mov edx,1     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
                     ;  mov edx,[helloLen] to get it's actual value
int 80h     

add [num1], byte '0'
mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
mov ecx,num1        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
mov edx,1     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
                    
int 80h     

end:

mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
mov ecx,hello        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
mov edx,helloLen     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
int 80h   


mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
int 80h;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just move them to registers and compare them

```
mov al, byte[num]

cmp al, byte[num1]
jg someLabelIfGreater
je someLabelIfEqual
; etc
```

If you are unsure whether you can use a particular combination of operands you can always check the reference.

https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html

As you can see the comparisons you can make are:

```
CMP AL, imm8      Compare imm8 with AL.
CMP AX, imm16     Compare imm16 with AX.
CMP EAX, imm32    Compare imm32 with EAX.
CMP r/m8, imm8    Compare imm8 with r/m8.
CMP r/m16, imm16. Compare imm16 with r/m16.
CMP r/m32,imm32   Compare imm32 with r/m32.
CMP r/m16,imm8    Compare imm8 with r/m16.
CMP r/m32,imm8    Compare imm8 with r/m32.
CMP r/m8,r8       Compare r8 with r/m8.
CMP r/m16,r16     Compare r16 with r/m16.
CMP r/m32,r32     Compare r32 with r/m32.
CMP r8,r/m8       Compare r/m8 with r8.
CMP r16,r/m16     Compare r/m16 with r16.
CMP r32,r/m32     Compare r/m32 with r32.
```

Here `r` stands for register, `m` for memory, `imm` for an immediate number which means numbers that you hardcode (like `0xF4` or something). There is no `cmp m8, m8` or equivalent thing in the list so you cannot compare these variables directly.